# Access http via IP on newly purchased server

Tags: http, ip-address, mediatemple

I've just purchased a VPS from Media Temple. I would like to migrate my Wordpress installation from an Amazon EC2 instance. My problem is that I can't install WP on the Media Temple server because I can't access the Document Root of my new account via http using directly it's server IP address.
Accessing it with the hostname won't work because the site is already up and running and I will change the DNS once I've installed everything on the new server.

Is there any way I could access my Media Temple server via http using only the IP address so that I could install WP?

Answer (score 1):

YES there is a way to do this.

- kinda tricky - but in short if you know the ip address you are using for the new website - you can make a change to your /etc/hosts (linux and MAC) or to your lmhost file (in Windows)

I will assume your using Windows first:

To use the LMHOSTS file, then you must configure LMHOSTS with the system name and IP address for iSeries NetServer to ensure client connectivity. To add an entry to the LMHOSTS file, follow these steps:

Go to the \WINNT\system32\drivers\etc directory.

Add the following entry to the LMHOSTS file:
TCP/IP-address domain name #comment
For example:

10.5.10.9 yourdomainname.com  #comment that you want goes here...

In windows Vista / 7

Open the lmhosts.sam file in Notepad. The lmhosts.sam file is located in:
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc or if your system hard drive isn't C: the path is whatever your system path would be: %systemroot%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Once you open the file, simply modify the lines you need for the IP addresses you want to map to network names in the pattern IP address first network name second.

Save the file as lmhosts (without the .sam) and your change will instantly be active.

In MAC or Linux

sudo nano /etc/hosts

ip-address domain-name # comment

10.4.2.1   domain.com www.domain.com #comment that you want to say

then save and clear your browser caches - and try to visit the site @ the new install :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Glenn. Actually I was already able to access the server I just didn't know I had access. I was shown a default index.html page that told me to add and setup my domain. The content of that page confused me, because I knew I did that.
Now I'm embarrassed...

Comment: No reason to be embarrassed.   Just remember we all start somewhere.

Comment: You made a wise move - and came to an online forum to ask...  Media Temple also has excellent support -    they are used to dealing with folks from all walks of life -  so don't hesitate to ask there either...